# Appropriate Way to Return Error in WCF

Tags: c#, vb.net, performance, wcf, iis

I am using WCF for REST API development.

We can return error codes by setting

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode
```

Currently I use following, because it provides cleaner and much visible code

```
Throw New WebFaultException(Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
```

But when using this method, if the exception is thrown frequently, IIS considers it as rapid fail and stops application pool according to Rapid Fail Protection Policy.

Is it the correct way to return errors and should I modify or turn off the Rapid Fail policy or is there any better way?

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize:

```
WebFaultException<T>(T detailedObject, HttpResponseCode code)
```

Where detailedObject is your custom response object and should be serializable.

Reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/01/21/error-handling-in-wcf-webhttp-services-with-webfaultexception.aspx

Comment: Yes but it would still be considered as application crash and IIS will still trigger rapid fail protection.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a response object like this:

```
public class WebServiceOutput
{
    public object Data { set; get; }        
    public bool HasError { set; get; }
    public string Code { set; get; }
    public string Description { set; get; }
}
```

then instead of throwing exceptions, you can return output with Boolean value.
telegram bot API is a good example.

Comment: Yes, nice idea. But then the service clients will have to unwrap the data and make an additional check for the Code with the status code check. And for serialization we will also need to annotate Data with KnownType for each new contract.

Comment: dear @RaviVadera. you are absolutely right about error check on client side. but its not a bad thing. its very common. we need to validate output after calling a web service. but about KnownType, i guess you didn't understand the concept of KnownType. you dont need annotate Data with KnownType at all.

Comment: So as long as each property of the DataContract is annotated with DataMember attribute, we don't need KnownType, am I right?

Comment: dear @RaviVadera If you expect the service to accept and return an inherited type then we use the knowntype attribute. you can use generic type to implement WebServiceOutput class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a out parameter and set in catch exception with exception message or a custom expression.
Write in service interface:

```
List<MyClass> GetResults(p1, out string message);
```

If you want to use a void method in service interface, you can change method return type to string and put error message as returen.

```
public string SaveResults(List<MyClass>)
```

After that, use define method in service like this:

```
public List<MyClass> GetResults(p1, out string message)
{
   string message;
   OperatorClass obj= new OperatorClass();
   return obj.GetResults(p1,out message);
}
```